# Would it be possible to create a file explorer for Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows-phone-7

I've looked around for a file explorer in windows' phone's marketplace, and couldn't find any (i'm speaking the kind of file explorer you get on Android to well... explore your files).
Would this be because Microsoft put a restriction on such applications?

If so, would you assume they just wouldn't accept it on the marketplace, or are there native restrictions to stop it from developing and using it on your phone?

Anticipated thanks :)

Comment: I'm afraid if that's possible, as Windows Phone platform from very origin doesn't support raw filesystem based access, and hence even for apps we create, we need to use, as Microsoft calls it, Isolated Storage, which is restricted to app that has created it. You may take a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402541(v=VS.92).aspx) article on Isolated storage. However, I'm not sure if this is also the case with Windows Phone 8, which has dramatic changes under-the-hood compared to WP7 or 7.5.

Answer (score 0):

There are api restrictions preventing your app from accessing everything except your local isolated storage. But there are special methods/hacks to give your app special permissions (similar to iPhone jailbreak) so that you can access file system, for example
http://www.wp7roottools.com/

But it is definitely a hack, so the answer is NO, you won't be able to implement such application and submit to the marketplace.